# Configurable product prices not changing when variation changed - Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.3.5, pricing

This issue appeared only with the new products that we recently imported into the Magento. All these new products have different attributes and attribute set.

Prices are still changing correctly on the old configurable products. So the issue is only with the new products.

Console error also displayed but that is generic

Answer (score 0):

We were using the 3rd party module for search.
That module have some conflict with these new products and upon specifically re-indexing of custom indexer associated with this 3rd party module this issue get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Please run the below command for re-indexing**

**php bin/magento i:rei**